# C# program that returns morse code for numbers not working

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a program that: When given a 4 digit number (for example, 1001) it sums the digits of that number, for 1001 this is 1 + 0 + 0 + 1 = 2, than it finds all sequences of 6 numbers from 1 to 6 (including permutations, i.e. 1*1*1*1*1*2 is different than 2*1*1*1*1*1) whose product is that number.

The result should be printed on the console in the following format: each sequence of 6 numbers, with their Morse representation, separated with a single pipe: 1 is `.----` , 2 is `..---`: `.----|.----|.----|.----|..---|`, on a new row the next permutation: `.----|.----|.----|..---|.----|` and so on.

The problem is, my solution doesn't show the correct answers, not even the correct number of them.

Here's my code (and please, if possible, tell me where my mistake is, and not some one line hack solutions to the problem with LINQ and regex and God knows what):

```
        string n = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] digitsChar = new string[n.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            digitsChar[i] = n[i].ToString();
        }
        int[] digits = new int[digitsChar.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            digits[i] = Convert.ToInt32(digitsChar[i]);
        }

        int morseProduct = digits.Sum();
        Console.WriteLine(morseProduct);

        List<int> morseCodeNumbers = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
                for (int k = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
                    for (int l = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
                        for (int m = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
                            for (int o = 1; o < 6; o++)
                            {
                                int product = i * j * k * l * m * o;
                                if (product == morseProduct)
                                {
                                    morseCodeNumbers.Add(i);
                                    morseCodeNumbers.Add(j);
                                    morseCodeNumbers.Add(k);
                                    morseCodeNumbers.Add(l);
                                    morseCodeNumbers.Add(m);
                                    morseCodeNumbers.Add(o);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }            
        }

        int numberOfNumbers = morseCodeNumbers.Count;
        string[] morseCodes = new string[] { "-----", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", "....." };

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNumbers; i++)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            if (i % 5 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                counter = 0;
            }
            if (counter < 5)
            {
                int index = morseCodeNumbers[i];
                Console.Write(morseCodes[index] + "|");
                counter++;
            }
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your samples. They contain only 5 digits. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of your for-loop conditions refer to i instead of j,k,l and m. The same for the increment part. For example:

```
for (int j = 1; i < 6; i++)
```

should be

```
for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++)
```

Furthermore if the range is from 1 to 6 you need to change < to <=, see:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
```

You don't need to convert the string to a string array to get the int array of digits btw, so while this is correct:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    digitsChar[i] = n[i].ToString();
}
int[] digits = new int[digitsChar.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    digits[i] = Convert.ToInt32(digitsChar[i]);
}
```

you could it do like that (sry for LINQ):

```
var digits = n.Select(c=>(int)char.GetNumericValue(c) ).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you! The dangers of copy-pasting loop conditions :D